# USB file transfer painfully slow - is this a solution in some cases?

Tags: installation, usb, files, transfer

A new Ubuntu user here.

**Case 1:**

System: F730 with 4 GB RAM - SUCCESS no problems

installed 2007 office

http://rmitc.org/2013/04/ultimate-microsoft-office-2010-installation-on-ubuntu/

Another link helped me to clean the bloatware (if I can say). My load averages fall to less than 2 (earlier it was around 3.5). For a naive user, it does look like this is good since I do not see any hang up or sluggishness in system response.

http://thanhsiang.org/faqing/node/189

I made a live CD for above installation.

**Case 2:**

System: Dell Dimension 4600, Pentium 4, 3 GB RAM with XP.

Installation of Ubuntu from XP - SUCCESS

Installation of Office (above method) - Success but took full night with load averages around 11. **FAIL**

Installation of Fonts (copied from another MS system), tried to transfer the folder (300 MB) onto Dimension 4600 - **FAIL**

**The Problem:** After plugging in USB onto Ubuntu (dual with XP), everything looks great. When I transfer the folder, the process starts. Initially, the speeds are high. 40 MB takes less few minutes (load average around 3), from around 40 - 60, 70 MB, it used to take another 3-4 minutes (load average around 6). From this point, the speed drops to literally few KB/sec if not less. The load average shoots to double digit. The system stops responding. Repeated numerous times. **No success.** This also happened if I tried to download any big file from internet as well. Poured over google and tried every possible solution out there. Tried updating graphics driver etc....EVERYTHING possible or mentioned in the context.

**NO SUCCESS.**

One thing over and over I came across is not every installation has this problem and only few people experienced this and even the developers are unable to recreate the problem. So deadend everywhere.

Finally decided to wipe the whole disc and start with fresh installation. Using live CD, I tired to install. I forgot my live CD was 64 bit and the hardware doesnot support 64 bit. The installation aborted.

I made a 32 bit live CD and installed everything including LXDE and Office. Everything was and is super fast now. NO PROBLEMS at all. The load average is between 1 and 2.

Is this at least a partial solution for painful USB transfer?? MAY BE...in my case it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This totally sounds like a disk/filesystem issue, especially since the problem could be seen when doing large file operations (downloading from usb/internet), and since it went away when you nuked the entire disk and reformatted.

People here could probably give you a better answer if you gave more info about your disk setup when you had the dual boot config.